# Feeding tuple into function such as printfn

Tags: f#, operators, tuples

I want to give a tuple to a `printf` function:

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")
do printfn "%s %s" tuple
```

This, of course, does not work, compiler first says, that it needs `string` instead of `string*string`. I write it as follows:

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")
do printfn "%s %s" <| fst tuple
```

Then compiler reasonably notes that now I have function value of type `string -> unit`. Makes sense. I can write

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")
do printfn "%s %s" <| fst tuple <| snd tuple
```

And it works for me. But I'm wondering, if there might be any way to do it nicer, like

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")
do printfn "%s %s" <| magic tuple
```

My problem is that I can't get which type does printf need so that to print two arguments.
What could `magic` function look like?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")   
printfn "%s %s" <|| tuple
```

Notice the double `||` in `<||` and not a single `|` in `<|`

See: [`<||`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#(%20%3C%7C%7C%20))

You can also do

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")
tuple
||> printfn "%s %s"
```

There are other similar [operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) such as `|>`, `||>`, `|||>`, `<|`, `<||`, and `<|||`.

A idiomatic way to do it using `fst` and `snd` is

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")
printfn "%s %s" (fst tuple) (snd tuple)
```

The reason you don't usually see a tuple passed to a function with one of the ||> or <|| operators is because of what is known as a **destructuring**.

A destructing expression takes a compound type and destructs it into parts.

So for the `tuple ("Hello", "world")` we can create a destructor which breaks the tuple into two parts.

```
let (a,b) = tuple
```

I know this may look like a tuple constructor to someone new to F#, or may look even odder because we have two values being bound to, (noticed I said bound and not assigned), but it takes the tuple with two values and destructured it into two separate values.

So here we do it using a destructuring expression.

```
let tuple = ("Hello", "world")
let (a,b) = tuple
printfn "%s %s" a b
```

or more commonly

```
let (a,b) = ("Hello", "world")
printfn "%s %s" a b
```

Comment: @Rustam I would suggest not using `magic` since it is not a standard way of doing things.  @GuyCoder has listed a couple of more idiomatic means of accomplishing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @mydogisbox Sure, I just wanted to understand how it could be done

Comment: First MSDN link is broken, so `||>` docs can be found at https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#(%20%7C%7C%3E%20)

Comment: @MattMS Thanks. Since the post is Creative Commons you could have just fixed the link instead of posting a comment.